# What are some good books on vector analysis in higher dimenesion

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, vector-analysis, book-recommendation

What is some good books specifically on vector analysis in higher dimension?

Standard vector calculus book usually only introduced double and triple integral method

Comment: Do you have a background in analysis?

Comment: Only on advanced calculus @snarski

Comment: Munkres: Analysis on Manifolds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, what you want is call "Functional Analysis" which deals with INFINITE dimensional vector spaces, I'd call that "higher" than 2-4 ;).

There are numerous texts on functional analysis. Papa Rudin, Reed's Mathematical Methods 1, Folland, etc. Here is a decent free textbook on it (used when I took functional analysis): https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/pdfbook.html

Although functional analysis can be very technical. You typically need a good background in upper division real analysis and topology.

If you are looking for more advanced stuff comparable to your vector calculus class, you should look into differential geometry. Munkres: Analysis on Manifolds is good. Do Carmo's Differential Geometry is really popular.

So if you're looking for "higher dimensional vector analysis", you're looking at functional analysis but that is intense. If you're looking for more vector calc, differential geometry is the next step.

Comment: While the OP is asking a book for higher dimensional vector analysis, something more than double/triple integral, it is obvious they are looking for higher, but finite dimension analogue.